# Eclipse says Can't find libc-start.c on ubuntu

Tags: c++, eclipse, ubuntu

I'm trying to do some C++ programing with eclipse on ubuntu.
Run works well. but there is something wrong with debug.
At the end of main(), eclipse tells me:

**Can't find a source file at "/build/buildd/eglibc-2.19/csu/libc-start.c"
Locate the file or edit the source lookup path to include its location.**

Someone in CSDN tells me that this is because a function will be called at the end of main() to clean up things, and this function is in libc-start.c, which doesn't exist in my system.
Can i do something to fix this?

thanks in advance

Comment: There's nothing that you need to do. You don't need to debug the code in  that file, not unless you want to work on the eglibc library.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg ^ this should be an answer. I can't see anything illegitimate in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.
Does this mean that I can continue debugging my code and the absence of libc-start.c won't cause me any problem unless I reach the end of main()?